# Set System propery to Null in Java

Tags: java, system-properties

In my unit tests I need to set the "workingDir" system property to Null.

But I can not do somesing like this, because It give me NullPointerException:

```
System.setProperty("workingDir", null);
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can't set a property to have an actual null value - you can only clear it, like this:

```
System.clearProperty("workingDir");
```

Answer (score 5):

`System.setProperty()` is internally implemented using a `Properties` object, which in turn uses the good old `Hashtable`. Those hashtables never let you set a null value using the`put()` method, so it can't really be done that way. Jon Skeet's post has the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it, as `setProperty` method throws NullPointerException if any of it's arguments is null. 
You can put an empty string there and check for it in your unit tests or simply clearProperty, as Jon suggested.