# GRADLE: TestNg - unable to pass -D parameter to java code

Tags: java, gradle, testng, command-line-arguments

I have a Test framework written in Java utilizing TestNg, and built using gradle.  I want to pass an 'environment' argument at the command line, which will be used in an Environment class to define domain and server values for specific environments.  Using the Gradle documentation and several forum discussions on this issue, I am still unable to get the argument passed as a system property to the framework.  I have tried to accomplish this from the 'test' task AND the 'debug' task, to NO avail.  A 'println' statement in the task shows that the -Denv parameter is being picked up by gradle, but my attempt to add it to the System properties for the test framework fails.

Execution results in a null reference, with environmentName being set to null.

Can someone identify my error?

command line

```
.\gradlew debug -Denv=production
```

build.gradle

```
test {
    def environment = System.properties["env"]
    println environment
    systemProperties = System.getProperties()
    systemProperties['env'] = environment
    useTestNG()
}

task debug(type: Test) {
//    def environment = System.properties["env"]
//    println environment
//    systemProperties = System.getProperties()
//    systemProperties['env'] = environment
    def groupsToInclude = []
    def groupsToExclude = []

    groupsToInclude.add('under_development')
    useTestNG() {
        groupsToInclude.each { String group -> includeGroups group }
        groupsToExclude.each { String group -> excludeGroups group }
    }
}
```

java class

```
import com.sun.javafx.runtime.SystemProperties;

public class Environment {

    private static EnvironmentDefinition environment;

    private Environment() {
    }

    public static EnvironmentDefinition getInstance() {
        if (environment == null) {
            String environmentName = SystemProperties.getProperty("env");
            // environmentName = environmentName == null ? "production" : environmentName;
            switch (environmentName) {
                default:
                    Environment.environment = ProductionEnvironment.getInstance();
            }
        }
        return environment;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help ... Add this as the line just before the `exec` in gradel shell-script -  `echo "$JAVACMD" "${JVM_OPTS[@]}" -classpath "$CLASSPATH" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "$@"
`. The next line should be exec. Report the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all works well, please have a look at the [demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/32815090) I prepared. Mind the fact that you [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323995/set-system-propery-to-null-in-java) set the system property to null value - it might be a problem as well.

Comment: Opal, thank you for the sample code.  It eventually led to my mistake.

Comment: @Craig, if you found it helpful, please at least upvote it.

Comment: Ah..newbie to submitting/responding to questions/answers in stackoverflow.  Your answer has been approved. =0)

Answer (score 1):

"It's System, you dummy...not SystemProperties!...

Isn't it always the most simple oversights that cause the most trouble?

After cloning Opal's solution along side mine, and bringing them into alignment one step at a time, I noticed that in the java code my reference was to **SystemProperties**.getProperty(), rather than **System**.getProperty().

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be to add the property in your `.gradle/gradel.properties` file, with the property set to what applies to that machine. See if that works. For example, you might set it to `DEV` on your machine, but `BUILD` on another machines. That way you don't have to enter it every time.
See this question about [customizing build by environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31964001/should-i-define-datasources-in-application-or-in-app-server/32240645#32240645). There are advantages and disadvantages to this approach.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, this approach would work if the tests were being executed on the machine being tested.  In this case, the tests are being executed on a separate machine (build slave), with access to multiple environments.  Test code being built and executed on the slave needs to know which urls and connection strings to use, based on the environment being validated.